# Detect Javascript/ECMAScript await misuse?

Tags: javascript, async-await, eslint, tslint

Is there a tool in the Javascript or Typescript ecosystem to detect the (mis/over)use of `await` on a synchronous function?  (e.g. a tslint rule)

The problem came up when I mistakenly used await for the result of synchronous function,

```
const decoded = await jsonwebtoken.verify(session, publicKey, opts);
```

which my linter, the default gts tslint, didn't catch.  The code oddly works (`await` silently passes non-promises?), but I'd like to flag the misuse to encourage use of an asynchonous/callback option.

I had thought that such misuse of `await` would trigger a Typescript error, but `tsc` and `ts-jest` pass the following test:

```
test('Demonstrate await', async () => {
  function foo(): number { return 4; }
  const food = await foo(); // Even replace foo() with a constant or literal.
  expect(food).toBe(4);
});
```

Comment: It's not an error, using `await` to values that aren't promises is perfectly legit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to enforce a linter rule like that if you use a type system. For TSlint you can use something like this:

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/await-promise/

Answer (score 1):

JS [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

> If the value of the expression following the `await` operator is not a `Promise`, it's converted to a resolved `Promise`.

So there is nothing wrong with that, it may be useful for testing or perhaps in live code too.

Answer (score 0):

If the awaited expression is not a promise, then it is wrapped in a promise, and then awaited.

Meaning you can put Objects, functions and even primitives and it will be treated as a promise.

Edit for source -- check this discussion here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8310

Comment: Remember to link to one or more sources that back up claims like this. Otherwise people have to just take your word for it, which isn't super great.

Comment: Note that that's not actually a great link to back up the claim that `await` behaves in a specific way: it's just a discussion thread on what typescript should do, without any links to official docs that explain how `await` has to behave based on the specification for the `await` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

An await acts on an expression. When the expression is a promise, the evaluation of the async function halts until the promise is resolved. When the expression is a non-promise value, it is converted to a promise using Promise.resolve and then resolved.